# Converting video for electron

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, ffmpeg, electron

I am currently working on a typescript-electron app that has a media component which should be able to play videos.

My electron app is a client that will play video located on a Java backend server. Problem is that the electron native player cannot play .mp4 or .avi formats.

What I aim to do is convert the videos to a electron friendly format. Problem is that I am not sure of the best approach for this task. I would use ffmpeg to convert video directly on the server, but not sure if this is the best solution.

Can somebody please give me some advice on how to tackle this?

Comment: What do you mean by Electron Native player? You can just use video.js or a similar js library to play video which is mp4 or avi. No conversion is required.

Comment: Electron is based on chromium engine and uses the chromium video player. Problem is that chromium video player does not support mp4/avi formats. I don't think video.js is much help here.

Comment: The native html5 video element does play mp4. I am not sure where you get this info that it does not play .mp4. See this https://www.chromium.org/audio-video. It is supported. You are probably getting some other error. The UI may say format not supported. But check the js console for the exact error. It may be something else.

Comment: What is the version of Electron you are using and which OS? What is the error message you are getting? I started getting an error "The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support" on MacOS, electron v 1.4.10. I do not get an error in Ubuntu for the same version.

Comment: The issue can be seen on some systems for some type of .mp4 files. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=586911. By disabling hardware acceleration for video on Chrome, I was able to get it to work.